# LSI Mega RAID in IBM x3690 - Hardware Failure move to spare system?

Tags: raid, ibm, lsi

I currently have a hardware failure with an IBM x3690 having 8 SAS disks connected to an LSI Mega RAID Controller.

I have a similar system (another x3690) can I place the RAID Controller and the disks into the new system and the Raid will work again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing the RAID controller and drives from the broken x3690 to the spare one, I was able to boot and access files without data loss.

In case you might need another RAID controller you must import (revocer) the RAID configuration from the disks "import foreign configuration(s)"

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/MegaRAID_Controller
https://www.schirmacher.de/display/Linux/MegaRAID:+All+of+the+disks+from+your+previous+configuration+are+gone
http://support.lenovo.com/in/hi/documents/ht079447